# $scope.$apply throwing exception...$scope.apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update my view based on the changes that I've made to my $scope variables in the middle of the digest for that after making the required changes to my variables i'm calling $scope.$apply(), which is actually causing an exception saying $scope.$apply already in progress. Can someone help me how to resolve this issue.

```
this.showCart = false;

/*This function is called from the view on a ng-click*/
this.addCart=function(){

        if (this.showCart === false) {
            this.showCart = true;
            this.hideEmptyCart = 'none';
            this.showFullCart = 'initial';
            this.searchRightMargin = 40;
            this.updateWidth();
            $scope.$apply();
        }
}
```

Comment: This error is informing you that the $scope.$apply is already in progress. You don't need to call it explicitly. Can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks Corey for the response, I've updated the post with some code.

Comment: You don't need to call `$scope.$apply()`. Just take it out and everything should work.

Comment: If I do that I don't see the updates happening right there, my cart is basically hidden. When I click an item to add to cart it should first shoe the cart and then the item should be added to the cart. I've an animation to fly the item on the cart, since my cart is hidden initially my item is being thrown to somewhere else on the screen instead of the cart for the first item, subsequent items works well. Do you know what can be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your problem is probably with the scope reference. Your `this` reference outside the function is scoped to the controller while your `this` reference inside the function is scoped to that function. Try changing everything to `$scope`:

```
$scope.showCart = false;

/*This function is called from the view on a ng-click*/
$scope.addCart=function(){
    if ($scope.showCart === false) {
        $scope.showCart = true;
        $scope.hideEmptyCart = 'none';
        $scope.showFullCart = 'initial';
        $scope.searchRightMargin = 40;
        $scope.updateWidth();
    }
}
```

Then, call your function from `ng-click`:

```
<button ng-click="addCart()">Add To Cart</button>
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you could try holding a reference to the controller as `self`:

```
var self = this;
self.showCart = false;

/*This function is called from the view on a ng-click*/
self.addCart=function(){
    if (self.showCart === false) {
        self.showCart = true;
        self.hideEmptyCart = 'none';
        self.showFullCart = 'initial';
        self.searchRightMargin = 40;
        self.updateWidth();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before just by changing the this.showCart to $scope.showCart, but now upon your suggestion I've tried changing everthing to $scope from this and it didn't help :(

Comment: There is likely another issue in your code. Perhaps a reference to the controller `as` in the markup. For example, changing `ctrl.addCart()` to `addCart()`. I have included another solution if you want to keep the controller `as`.